# Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is neither bounded below nor bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is neither bounded below nor bounded above. Suppose that $f(0)=0$. Show that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $\{x_k\}$ of zeros of $f$, that is, $f(x_k)=0$ for all $k=1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots,n,n+1,\ldots$

I know that $f$ must be of the type $x\sin x$. But how to prove this fact. Please help

Comment: this is not true we must have additional conditions. For example $f(x)=x$ do satisfy your conditions but it doesn't have your wanted property

Comment: By using the fact that $f$ is unbounded above/below, find a monotone sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $f(x_{2k})>0$ and $f(x_{2k+1})<0$.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç $f(x)=x$ is bounded below on $[0,\infty).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes thank you, then my answer is wrong. But i don't want to delete it. It is "let's say" worth looking sidenote.

Comment: _Hint_: if $f$ had a finite number of zeros, then it has a maximum zero, say at $x_0$, so $f(x_0)=0$ and $x_0$ is the largest number with this property. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,x_0]$, it should be bounded on this domain, right? What happens after $x_0$?

Comment: It's interesting that the question asks only for a strictly increasing sequence of zeroes, when the assumptions actually imply that the set of zeroes is unbounded. (The suggested solutions only require a small tweak to give this.)

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume we have finitely many $0$'s. Then there exists finitely many $x_1, ..., x_k$ that satisfies $f(x_i)=0$. Which means for all $x>x_k$ our function $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$. But this implies $f(x)$ is either bounded below or bounded above(Because of continuity).

Comment: There's a slight gap in this presentation.  Note that because $f$ is continuous and $[0, x_k]$ is compact, $f$ is necessarily bounded in $[0, x_k]$.  Thus, since $f$ is unbounded above and below, it must be unbounded above and below in the interval $(x_k, \infty)$, or alternatively, since $f$ can't be unbounded both above and below in that interval (because it has no zeroes there), it is either bounded above or bounded below, contradicting our hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof (which, out of interest, does not involve a compactness argument) of a stronger result: if $f : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous and not bounded below or above, then the set of zeroes of $f$ is unbounded (and hence certainly contains a strictly increasing sequence). (Roughly speaking, all the proof really depends on is that $f(x)$ keeps changing sign as $x$ grows, so you can make the assumptions even weaker, if you wish.)

To see this, first note that $f$ has at least one zero: by assumption, there are $x$ and $y$ in $[0, \infty)$ such that $f(x) > 1$ and $f(y) < 1$. By the intermediate value theorem, this means that there is a $t$ in the open interval $(\min(x, y), \max(x, y))$ such that $f(t) = 0$.

Now let $z \in [0, \infty)$ be given, then, applying what we have just proved to the function $g: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = f(x - z)$, we find there is a $t'> 0$ such that $f(t' +z ) = g(t') = 0$ and $t' > z$. So for any $z$, we have $u = t' + z > z$, with $f(u) = 0$. I.e., the zeroes of $f$ are unbounded.